# Is there more than 3 types of mixed modeling?

Tags: mixed-model

I'm working on learning more about mixed models. So I've been trying to teach myself each mixed model that I can find and how to interpret it. So long I've made this table and I thought it might be useful for other people learning about mixed models:

| Model Type | Sample Type | Computational Cost | Random Effects | Fixed Effects | Modeling Non-Normal Dependent Variables | Modeling Non-Linear Relationships | Nested Data Usage | Example Application |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Linear Mixed Models | Normal or Non-Normal | Medium to High | Yes | Yes | No | No | Yes | Longitudinal study with repeated measurements |
| Generalized Mixed Models | Non-Normal | Medium to High | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | Yes | Analysis of categorical or count data |
| Nonlinear Mixed Models | Normal or Non-Normal | High | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Modeling non-linear relationships |

I am not sure if with this table I have managed to collect all the types of mixed models that there are. I am also trying to understand them correctly, so maybe there is some column or some data that I can modify.

I have based myself on the book "[introduction to mixed models](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/314536942_Introduccion_a_los_modelos_mixtos_Introduction_to_mixed_models)" by Juan Carlos Correa Morales, also in Mixed Models. [Theory and Applications](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263152786_Mixed_Models_Theory_and_Applications_by_E_Demidenko) by E. Demidenko , in [Mixed Linear Models in R](https://www.academia.edu/8533347/Modelos_lineales_mixtos_en_R) byLuis Cayuela and in Linear and Generalized [Linear Mixed Models and Their Applications](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-47946-0) by Jiming Jiang. So if there is any book that you can recommend to me, it would also be appreciated.

Comment: There are as many types of mixed models as there are types of fixed models. A mixed model is a fixed effects model where some of the fixed effects are treated as a source of noise that is to be sampled from some random distribution.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus You're right, in the fourth category I wanted to gather those mixed models that you can include random effects, but by definition, mixed models include random and fixed effects. I'll change the question, thanks!

Comment: The thing @SextusEmpiricus is that, from what I'm learning, each method of applying a mixed model differs from the way of applying a fixed model. So I wanted to see the differences between them. I don't know whether to assume that the difference between a fixed model and a random model has no implications other than that random effect is correct. That is, I understand that the interpretation, capabilities, computational needs, method and mathematical explanation will also be affected.So I want to make a summary of the main virtues of each model.

Comment: The problem is that your question is very broad and a bit subjective. It depends on how you perform the classification. Consider an analoguous question "are there more than 3 types of people?"

Comment: Other complicating factors include type of estimator, e.g., OLS, MLE, GEE, metropolis-hastings, etc. Then there are time series issues affecting covariance structures in mixed models. And don't forget the distinctions between finite mixture and Bayesian hierarchical models. It's much more nuanced than your table allows.

Comment: I think I understand, @MikeHunter . Instead of proposing a table as a summary, I can propose that mixed models are an extension of fixed models, so I have to attend to each model characteristic to be able to use them properly and extract meaningful data?